# Whats the best way to insert content into an HTML document with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I was wondering sense there were so many ways to add content dynamically, which way is better.
I know of only of three methods
that add to a body's text node

```
document.body.innerHTML+="<div>"+myContent+"</div>";
```

add to the current text node

```
document.write("<div>"+myContent+"</div>");
```

and add a whole new node

```
//case based but for example purpose
var node = document.createElement("div");
node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myContent));
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

The third example is obviously more lines. Which is why I'm wondering why I should even consider it. Given download times tend to be worse off then parse times?

Comment: The third is best. Please not the second. The first is mediocre. This question is too opinion based though, and since that type of question has historically been problematic here they tend to be closed.

Comment: This question is way too broad. If you could tie it to an example of what you're trying to do and include some code that would be better.

Comment: Use gzip compression at the server level will help with download times. The third is the best out of the three, as Travis J said.

Comment: Just to understand you problem, you are chasing bytes here? The longest is less than 150bytes long. Use a function if you use it twice will reduce you problem. I wirte it in 107bytes (can probably by reduce more).

Comment: If you are looking at a larger scope, please consider something like AngularJS, EmberJS, React... These frameworks/libraries are specially built to do this kind of things.

Comment: All those methods are used in different situations. You just can't pick the best in general, pick the one which best suits to a use-case you've at hands.

Comment: To determine "best" there must be criteria for evaluation. "More/less code" is not a valid criterion of itself.

Comment: you're missing other solutions like `insertAdjacentHTML` or appending document fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> document.body.innerHTML+="<div>"+myContent+"</div>";
> ```

- Destroys any existing event handlers and form data, and creates new elements from the generated source code.
- Doesn't safely escape `myContent`.

> ```
> document.write("<div>"+myContent+"</div>");
> ```

- Wipes out the entire document if it is in a closed state
- Doesn't safely escape `myContent`.

> ```
> var node = document.createElement("div");
> node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myContent));
> document.body.appendChild(node);
> ```

- Verbose, but safe

---

Option 3 is usually the best.

---

> The third example is obviously more lines. Which is why I'm wondering why I should even consider it. Given download times tend to be worse off then parse times?

Micro-optimisations generally aren't worth the effort. Most of the size difference will be eliminated by HTTP compression anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** `document.body.innerHTML+="<div>"+myContent+"</div>";`

Useful when you inserting static HTML (Event Listener not required) in to specific `<element>`. In this case performance is good.

**2)** `document.write("<div>"+myContent+"</div>");`
I will not recommend this way to do. This will overwrite full page.

**3)** Useful in case Event Listener adding dynamically.

```
var node = document.createElement("div");

// You can Add Event here.
node.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("Event Added"); });

node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myContent));
document.body.appendChild(node);
```